# How to pass a block as an argument into another block in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, syntax, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to define a block that takes a block as an argument.

What's wrong with the following line of code?

```
id (^cacheResult)(NSString *, id(^)(void)) = ^(NSString *name, id(^)(void)block) {
    NSObject *item = nil;
    block();
    return item;
};
```

Why does the compiler keep giving errors like `Parameter name omitted` and `Expected ")"`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
id (^cacheResult)(NSString *, id(^)(void)) = ^(NSString *name, id(^block)(void)) {
    NSObject *item = nil;
    block();
    return item;
};
```

Blocks have similar syntax to function pointers. You have to declare block name after the ^

Answer (score 10):

This is why `typedef` was invented. Embedding function pointers or block types like this is a pain. Try this instead:

```
typedef id (^ InnerBlock)(void);
typedef id (^ OuterBlock)(NSString *, InnerBlock);
```

It'll make working with block types a lot easier to read. :)

Comment: ah, thanks for the pointer(no pun intended). I find blocks definition really hard to read sometimes and typedef is indeed the perfect solution! Though my particular error was misunderstanding where to place the block variable name.

Answer (score 3):

Did you possibly mean `id(^block)(void)` on the RHS of the assignment?